# When "you're going too fast" popup shows does it still track egg tracking when going slower again?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever you are in a car and go too fast the popup of "you're going too fast" shows up and you can click "I'm a passenger". Now I know that it won't track eggs when you're going too fast. But what if you're going slowly later on due too traffic jam or whatever but still have the popup showing because you didn't click it yet?

The reason I ask is that I want to keep the app running while I'm driving but I don't want to pay attention to the screen (because I'm driving) so I can't click the "I'm a passenger" button.

EDIT:
While the question of the possible duplicate "What happens if I don't acknowledge that I'm a passenger?" should answer my question I think it isn't answered for my case. The answer there doesn't take into account egg hatching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I don't acknowledge that I'm a passenger?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281878/what-happens-if-i-dont-acknowledge-that-im-a-passenger)

Comment: The post states that nothing special happens when this pop up is up. So all the regular functionnalities applies.

Answer (score 3):

After it caches you going faster than permitted, It checks few times to make sure you've actually slowed down before it starts tracking again. So while driving, after the first several second - it stops tracking and will not restart, until you stop and walk. I've tested this myself, there is this long quite street near my house that I'd go as slow as possible with my car, never had a single cm tracked on there.